# Cannot enable xdebug on Macbook

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_host' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_host (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_port' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_port (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
PHP 8.0.6 (cli) (built: May 13 2021 05:28:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I need help, this is the output from `php -v` as you can see xdebug is enabled. Am using PHP 8 etc...

But xdebug is still not working within PHP storm. The PHP Warning appears whether that file exists or not, even when I remove it having followed other posts/articles etc but no success...

xdebug is configured under CLI Intepreters and shows up but still not run correctly.

Output of `php -m`

```
Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_host' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_host (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_port' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_port (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
phpdbg_webhelper
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: Can you provide your phpinfo output or php -m to make the situation more clear?

Comment: @TarasBudzyn updated with the output.

Comment: ok, great. Now we also need the output configuration of your xdebug, as I see warnings there.

Comment: How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug.so' (tried: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.6_1/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0`

Indicates that you're trying to load Xdebug **twice**. One time successfully so that it shows up in `php -m`, and one time with the wrong path, which gives this error. You need to find the wrong line in all of the ini files that are being loaded. You can find all the ini files that are being loaded with `php --ini`.

```
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_host' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_host (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_port' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_port (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
```

These warnings are because you're making Xdebug 3 settings, which have been renamed to something else as this warning indicates. To solve that, read the upgrading guide that these warnings point to **in the message**.

Comment: Cheers. Turns out that it was partially the xebug3 setup and partially having legacy php unfinished setup on the system. 

Once I updated the php.ini and removed the duplicate `zend_extensions` it all started working fine.